# DB Connection Setup with Factory Pattern not returning ConnectionString

Tags: c#, factory-pattern

I am looking to setup a Factory to get my connection to my database. I thought I had set everything up correctly, but I must be missing something because my `ConnectionString` is not returning when I use `.CreateConnection()`.

My thoughts are that I missed something in my App.config connection string for this to not be working.

This is my first time trying to do this and I was hoping someone could explain to me what I am missing. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
const string SQL_CONNECTION_KEY = "MSDBConnection";
var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[SQL_CONNECTION_KEY];
var providerName = connString.ProviderName;
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(providerName);
var conn = factory.CreateConnection();
```

`var conn` does not seem to populate with my App.config connection... Here is my `ConnectionString`:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MSDBConnection" connectionString="server=.;database=msdb;user id=UserName;password=Password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Again, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the connection string on your connection.  Try this.

```
conn.ConnectionString = connString.ConnectionString;
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you for the help! I will mark you as the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: You might want to rename `connString` to `connStringSetting` for better clarity.